# MediaPlayer on Android only plays part of my song :(

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play a file using the MediaPlay.  The first time it is played, it only plays for 1 or 2 seconds then cuts out and never returns.  The second time I play the song, it goes about 3 seconds.  This function is in the onCreate function:

```
checkin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.my_song);
   mp.start();
   v.vibrate(500);
   myLocation.getLocation(context, locationResult);
}
```

Is another thread clearing overriding the song?  How do I get my whole song to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling start() too quickly, before player actually loads all it needs to play the song. Use setOnPreparedListener() to start playing after the song is prepared for playback.